# Does "len" of a list get recalculated in every iteration of a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to eliminate all columns of a dataframe with a date before the year 2000.

The general approach is:

```
columnstokeep = list(DF) #gives me the column names

    for i in range(len(columnstokeep)): #get rid of dates before year 2000
        if int(columnstokeep[i][:4])<2000:
            columnstokeep.remove(columnstokeep[i])

DF = DF[columnstokeep]  #the new dataframe
```

I keep running into an list index out of range error.

Is this because len, in range(len(columnstokeep)) is changing each time I drop an element of the list?  Or does range(len(columnstokeep)) hold the same value for the duration of the loop?

Here is the Dataframe

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of the dataframe?

Comment: It's possible that you want "for i in range(len(columnstokeep)-1)"

Comment: There's multiple duplicates on why you shouldn't alter list length while iterating through it. Rebuild the list instead. But they're not really relevant with pandas because there should be a need to iterate like this in the first place. Can you show an example of the df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily using [`pd.to_datetimes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) on the columns, then selecting the ones greater than `2000`.

```
# Create Example Data
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    '1998-1-1': ['foo'],
    '1999-1-1': ['bar'],
    '2000-1-1': ['spam'],
    '2001-1-1': ['eggs']
})

# Select columns which are after 2000
frame.loc[:,pd.to_datetime(frame.columns) >= '2000']
```

Output:

```
  2000-1-1 2001-1-1
0     spam     eggs
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right with your regards about the root of the problem. But I don't hink the range gets recalculated. But since you remove the first values from the list `i` will outrange the remaining `columnstokeep`. I added some prints to show the problem more clearly:

```
years = range(1990,2010) 
columnstokeep=[]
#The column names kind of
for i in years:
    columnstokeep.append(str(i)+'-01')

##This shows the error comment this
for i in range(len(columnstokeep)-1): #get rid of dates before year 2000
    print(i,columnstokeep[i])#It prints every second year while in 199X

    if int(columnstokeep[i][:4])<2000:
        columnstokeep.remove(columnstokeep[i])
```

Instead you could iterate from end tobeginning....

```
for i in range(len(columnstokeep)-1,-1,-1): #get rid of dates before year 2000
    print(i,columnstokeep[i])#It prints every second year while in 199X

    if int(columnstokeep[i][:4])<2000:
        columnstokeep.remove(columnstokeep[i])



#DF = DF[columnstokeep]  #the new dataframe
print(columnstokeep)
```

output:

```
['2000-01', '2001-01', '2002-01', '2003-01', '2004-01', '2005-01', '2006-01', '2007-01', '2008-01', '2009-01']
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why it is skipping every other element before it hits 2000, when we iterate up?  Thank you.

Comment: Ah - got it! @ columnstokeep[0], the value gets deleted.  So if the length of the list decreases, it then skips to columnstokeep[1], but there is a new columnstokeep[0] that is ignored.

Comment: @ZakS  Thanks for the upvote. I added some more explenation.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the range len isn't the root of the issue, which is the skipping of the iterator over one element, when iterating upwards.  Finally got there.  Thanks for the clear explanation.